# Changing the location of the text without css

Tags: html

Its look like:

[image]

But, is that possible to move this text (Lepingute ajalugu) to here without CSS :

[image]

I want this text directly under it (LEPINGUD). Is that possible ?

My html:

```
<ul class="list-inline choose-actions">
                <li><h4>Lepingud</h4> |</li>
                <li>Lepingute allkirjastamine |</li>
                <li>Esita muutmisavaldus |</li>
                <li>Lepingute ajalugu</li>
</ul>
```

I already tried spaces and use `<br>`, but I didnt get what I need.

Any clue ?

**UPDATE**

Like all said, I need to use CSS, how I can move `<li>Lepingute ajalugu</li>` a little bit right. I tried this :

```css
ul li li li li{
    left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><h4>Lepingud</h4> |</li>
    <li>Lepingute allkirjastamine |</li>
    <li>Esita muutmisavaldus |</li>
    <li>Lepingute ajalugu</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"without CSS"* - Why?

Comment: You could do it with Javascript also but it begs the question again... Why no CSS?

Comment: try `&nbsp;` but it is bad, bad (really bad) bad practice! CSS is the way to style stylings

Comment: If you turn off all css, there will be only single line of text. Why not use CSS for stuff that requires CSS?

Comment: I 'd like to go easier way , and Im not good in CSS

Comment: So maybe it's time to learn CSS or leave front-end related thing and move on with something else?

Comment: I suck in CSS, and I dont know how I should do to this with CSS

Comment: @Justinas no, there are the default rules for `<h(1,2,3,4,5)>`  and `<ul><li>` tags but they are already overwritten if he has the layout he has

Comment: Yes maybe it is time to learn CSS , but I need to do this fast . :S

Comment: CSS is fastest and best way in this situation

Comment: I believe , but I dont know how do to this.

Comment: @frantsium can you make a fiddle

Comment: If I make fiddle, then Its look different

Comment: I have many ul's and li's in html, I need to do something like this ? `ul li li li li ul li li li { left: 15px; }`

Answer (score 0):

No, and even if yes: don't do it. HTML should describe the logical structure of the document - what is a header, what is a paragraph, what is an acronym etc. The browsers have some default (mostly standardized) assumptions about default formatting of specific items (like bolding  items). If you don't like the defaults, you use CSS - either as an actual stylesheet (embed in , or linked as a separate file) or inline style="..." attributes on elements.

If you don't want to use CSS at all, then you are stuck with defaults. The other option (using `&nbsp;` or other horrible ways of moving content around) are not guaranteed to actually work the same way on every browser/device, and in the future that behaviour can change without notice. Also, it's just wrong :)

CSS is not really difficult - grab a basic tutorial [like this one on W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) and simply experiment around with your page until you get results you like :) You don't need any special IDE or compiler or anything - just try something, save and refresh!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul class="list-inline choose-actions">
 <li><h4>Lepingud</h4> |</li>
 <li>Lepingute allkirjastamine |</li>
 <li>Esita muutmisavaldus |</li>
 <li>Lepingute ajalugu</li>
 </ul>
 ul tag width fix provide then li tag padding left provide
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can´t. You need CSS. I should see your code in action to help you more but you could try:

```
<h4 style="margin-left:0;">
```

I dont know if it solves your problem ¿could you provide us an url that contains your code?

Note: Learn CSS, its very important for a web developer :)

Comment: Its not helping :S I have so many ul's and li's, I need to do something like this ? `ul li li li li ul li li li {
 left: 15px;
}`